# Analytic continuation of the cardinality of a set: -1/2 element sets? Sets with an imaginary number of elements?

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, elementary-set-theory, gamma-function, analytic-continuation

The number of r-element subsets of a set of cardinality n is given by $_nC_r$, with is equivalent to the factorial expression $$\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$$ Well, whenever I see a factorial I get the urge to analytically continue it with the gamma function, which would make the expression above $$\frac{Γ(n+1)}{Γ(r+1)Γ(n-r+1)}$$ Which gave me the idea to find the number of $i$-element subsets in a $1/2$-element set, or $$\frac{Γ(3/2)}{Γ(i+1)Γ(3/2-i)}$$ Which, according to Wolfram Alpha, has a value of approximately $2.62 + 1.28i$. What I'm wondering is how a set of non-integer cardinality could be interpreted? Has anybody done any work on this subject? Or have I stumbled upon a new and probably useless area of set theory?

Comment: While the mathematical object can indeed be extended, its extension no longer has anything to do with the combinatorial property of the original object. We already see this with the positive integers (which were invented to denote cardinalities of finite sets) and negative integers/rational numbers/etc. (which are mathematical extensions only).

Comment: Extending the definition of binomial coefficients to the gamma function generally divorces it from the combinatorial meaning of the binomial coefficients. That is, I do not think it really makes sense to ask what $i$-element subsets or sets with $1/2$ elements mean. However, there are some interesting results about taking a counting function and plugging in negative integers, then getting a meaningful quantity counting something related to your problem -- this is called "combinatorial reciprocity", perhaps the most famous example being the chromatic polynomial and acyclic orientations.